# Upgrading DB in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am aware of how the upgrade method works, I am confused at certain points:

1) At the start my DB version was 1 my app version was 1.

2) Now I upgraded my DB version to 2 and my app version is 2.

3) I want to upgrade DB to 3 and app to 3.

Question: What happens to people who are upgrading from app version 1 to app version 3? Will they get the upgrade of DB to 2 and then to 3? Or do I need to write code for that? How do I maintain such flags?

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349902/how-to-deal-with-multiple-database-version-changes-when-android-application-upda ?

Comment: Here's the solution for your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133597/android-upgrading-db-version-and-adding-new-table]

Answer (score 2):

Well, SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade will be called as usual, and the simplest way to handle this is to have your upgrade code handle each version step-wise; from version 1 -> 2 -> 3 etc. For example:

`public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        // upgrade db to version 2
        oldVersion = 2;
    }
    if (oldVersion == 2) {
        // upgrade db to version 3
        oldVersion = 3;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

usually, when the DB upgrade is incremental, you could use an elegant `switch`:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  switch( oldVersion ){
    case 1:
      migrateFrom1();
    case 2:
      migrateFrom2();
    case 3:
      migrateFrom3();
  }
}
```

notice the absence of `break` statements.

Comment: Since when are switches elegant LOL? And this particular one with no breaks or returns in each case gives me the chills.

Comment: I found an elegant way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349902/how-to-deal-with-multiple-database-version-changes-when-android-application-upda)

Comment: @User3 I don't see how that is more elegant, it requires one piece of code for each combination of old and new version. Consider what this would look like in a database at version 50.
In my opinion it's better, clearer and less error-prone (because you can actually test all cases easily) to handle upgrades step-wise in deltas.