# sql onUpgrade for new users

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, upgrade

This is a trivial question, but I am afraid to put in production wrong code and that testing in devices/emulator could lead to cache problems that do not mirror the reality.

**My assumptions:**

As well documented on SO, I need to add a column to my DB, I decided to use `ALTER table ADD column` 
in onUpgrade(), and to change the version in the constructor of the DB from 1 to 2, so that the constructor will recognize that is running the new version and the onUpgrade()  function should be triggered.

**My 2 problems:**

1) MOST IMPORTANT. Let's assume old users will upgrade successfully the db, but what happens with *new users* that still have to create even the first row of the DB, will they be directed to OnCreate() and not onUpgrade() because version is 2, or to on OnCreate() and **then** onUpgrade(), or almost impossible directly in OnUpgrade() skipping for some API reason even onCreate()?

In other terms do I need to update the new column **changing the old onCreate()** comprehending the new added column?

2) in onUpgrade() after

```
ALTER <table> ADD <column>
```

logically do I have to CREATE a new table right? Should I call onCreate() that as an updated Table( ex. instead of the original 4 column, now has 5 columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `getWritableDatabase()` is called, it checks the database file. If it does not exist, `onCreate` is called. If it does exist, but has a wrong version, `onUpgrade` is called.

So `onCreate` is responsible for creating the database schema of the *current* version, while `onUpgrade` is responsible for changing some existing database to have the schema of the current version.

You could share code between `onCreate` and `onUpgrade`, but calling that code is your own responsibility; the framework will not check the version again after the `onXxx` callback has returned.

Comment: so when I update the db adding one column, should I update also onCreate() to take care of the "new users" or setting an updated version in the contructor, everybody will go trough onUpgrade? Please @CL could you reply to my 2 questions more explicitely? thanks

Comment: Yes, update onCreate() to take care of new users and update onUpgrade() for existing. New users won't go through onUpgrade and existing users won't go through OnCreate. Things get more complex when you have more than two versions to consider. See my old answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349902 to a similar question which gives a worked example.